# How to code mac os x status bar app to send cURL command

Tags: xcode, macos, curl, cloudflare

#### Briefly

I want to code a status bar app that will send commands through an https connection using PHP / cURL.

#### What I Have and Know

1. Mac OS X running Mountain Lion (with X-code)
2. Extra-beginner coding skills in Objective-C
3. An API's documentation with instructions on what text to send via PHP/cURL
4. YouTube tutorial: [Xcode 4.1 Tutorial - Create a menu bar application (NSStatusItem / StatusBar app) + DOWNLOAD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRPMFNDcfLY)
5. Interest in starting simple, but building to more complexity

#### What I Don't Have or Know

1. How to code the POST/GET commands into the app so that they fire upon click.

#### The Specific Use Case

I want to create a very basic status bar app that does two things related to the Cloudflare CDN / proxy app. [CloudFlare's API](http://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html) allows for commands to a user's account sent over https with PHP / CURL commands.

I'd like to build a status bar app with hard wired commands executable via click. The click would perform either a mode change (like entering development mode) for a website, or a cache purge for the website. These are tasks that can be performed in the front end of the CloudFlare website and the API docs give some very clear direction on how to structure the GET/POST requests (so no help is needed on that end of things).

#### Gratitudocity

I'm super grateful in advance to anyone who can provide me with some pointers, resources, or additional things to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not going to answer the part about setting up the status bar and adding status bar items and connecting them to actions in your controller, but I will point you in the direction of NSURLConnection and NSMutableURLRequest, rather than curl.

Example:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.example.com"]];
[req setAllHTTPHeaderFields:@{@"header1":@"value1"}];
[req setHTTPBody:[NSData data]];//not really doing anything
[req setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLResponse * respMeta = nil; //will contain returned headers, etc
NSError * err = nil; // on failure will contain error object
NSData * response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&respMeta error:&err];
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Grady. Can you explain briefly why those two class references make more sense than looking into cURL?

Comment: because they are OS X classes that use cocoa objects, and can call objective c code directly... as a block or delegate callback... let me make a quick demo for you.

Comment: Thanks for that demo Grady. It's giving me more direction on what areas I need to be more knowledgeable about to get going.